# If $a_1=1$ and $a_n=\sec (a_{n-1})$ then what does the proportion of positive terms approach, as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ergodic-theory, limits-and-convergence, trigonometric-functions

Consider the sequence $a_1=1$ and $a_n=\sec (a_{n-1})$ for $n>1$.

[image]

> What does the proportion of positive terms approach, as $n\to\infty$?

At first [I thought the limiting proportion might be](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4781942/398708) $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\approx 0.3989$, but perhaps not.

Comment: Unlikely this is possible prove for the first term $a_1=1$ or any other specific first term. But if it is random, the thing to do is to find the invariant measure and apply pointwise ergodic theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}$
A quick heuristic argument: we can assume that values of secant mod $\pi$ are equidistributed. Then using symmetry, consider the graph of secant over the $[0, \pi/2]$ interval; we just need to look at the subintervals that go to $[0, \pi/2], [3\pi/2, 5\pi/2],\ldots$ and see what portion of that interval they make up. This suggests that the value should be $\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\arcsec(\frac\pi2)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\arcsec(\frac{(4i+1)\pi}2)-\arcsec(\frac{(4i-1)\pi}2)\right)\right)$ (where all values of $\arcsec$ here are taken in that $[0,\pi/2]$ interval) but I'd be surprised if there were a closed form for that.

Comment: The value of your expression is approximately $0.6485$, which is quite different from the approximation I got by running an Excel simulation, which was about $0.3989$.